# Selenium IDE Basic Authentication

Tags: selenium-ide, basic-authentication

Im am using Firefox Plugin Selenium IDE for testing (not Webdriver or else). Some areas of my webapplication are only accessible after basic authentication:

[image: basic auth window]

At the moment, I have to stop the test and type the login-data manually. When I pass my login-data via url: `http://username:password@mydomain.com/`, there appears a windows, where I cannot press the OK-Button via Selenium IDE:

[image: basic auth url warning]

Is there any way to login via Selenium IDE automatically?

Comment: is this your browser proxy authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one soulution by myself: Firefox plugin AutoAuth. Typing login and password at first time, using "Save Password" -function in Firefox, the Plugin AutoAuth sends Login-Data automatically, if authentication window appears next time.

Note: AutoAuth-plugin can´t be used, if the login-account has to be changed in context of Selenium-test.

Answer (score -2):

To switch users when the site is using basic auth, you can specify the username and password in the URL you pass to the open command in the IDE.

Viewing the source code in the IDE it could look like this if you want to be first "user1" then "user2".

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://user1:pwd1@site.my/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>http://user2:pwd3@site.my/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Simple code is not consider a proper answer, please add some information too.

Comment: On a related note. Please use the given proper formatting tools. See [Formatting Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)